# why does android udp-socket lose packets using the method of socket.recieve()?

Tags: android, sockets, udp, packet, android-networking

I just try to use the `recieve()` method of the socket.

- When I send the data of a short String,as `"send data"`,for 100
  times,the recieve() function performs well.
- While  I send the data of a long String,as `"send data to the
  client,send data to the client,send data to the client,send data to
  the client,send data to the client,send data to the client,send data
  to the client,send data to the client"`,for 100 times,the recieve()
  function cannot performs well.

In android project:

It just recieved about 30 packets, that is, other 70 packets are lost when I use another computer to send pakcets. But I checked the recieve buffer size, it is adequate to contain 100 packets above.

It recieves all the 100 packets when I use the localhost address to test. And I used the capturing tool named wireshark to capture the packets and the capturing tool can capture all the 100 packets everytime.

So I can eliminate the possibility of that another computer did not send all the packets.So I included that the problem exists in the emulator.

The above two cases both happened in android project,so the recieve buffer size is the same, 
why in the former it will lose packets??

In java project:It recieves all the 100 packets too.

Comment: All UDP sockets lose packets. It has nothing to do with Java or Android specifically. It's an unreliable protocol, by design.

Answer (score 0):

If you need all the packets then you should use TCP/IP protocol. In UDP protocol you can lose data because it is doesnot support reliable connection like Tcp/ip. UDP is designed to be faster at transferring data at the cost of unreliable connection. Based on network routing the packets you received could also arrive in different order.

Answer (score 0):

Emulator TCP/IP stack's udp buffer size is smaller than the computer. So if the UDP buffer fills up, the emulator TCP/IP stack starts dropping packet. The PC TCP/IP stack pushes data at faster rate which the emulator can't handle. You can try reducing the rate at sender end to avoid filling the emulator buffer or increase the receive socket buffer size of android app to higher value by using the SO_RCVBUF socket option.

Comment: I cannot agree with you more.You are right,but why the socket.setRecieveBufferSize() just can not work on the emulator? Maybe it will perform well on the true adroid device.Thank you again for reading my poor english sentences with patience!